# 'string' is not able to assign to Nullable<T>

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have below typeScript code in which i am trying to assign either 'string' or 'null' value

```
type MyValue = "A" | "B" | "C"
type Nullable<T>  = T | null

let a: Nullable<MyValue> = null
```

Now, when i am trying to assign value to `a` as

```
   if(parentArr.length > 0){
     for (let i = 0; i < parentArr.length; i++) { 
     if (arr[i].length > 0) {
         arr.forEach(element => {
          if (true) {
             a = arr[i].name
        }
   });                 
   }
   }
```

its giving error like

> string' is not able to assign to Nullable

. What's wrong here?

Comment: well `a` is const to begin with

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski my bad, its actually a `let`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue then, copied your code and run it with typescript 3.9.6, didn't show any errors, are you sure it's not a editor related issue? maybe it's outdated version of typescript?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Its giving error to me at 3.7.5

Comment: is this really all of your code? even with typescript 3.7.5 i still cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski depends on your strict setting i guess

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I have updated my code in the post, please have a look.

Comment: @Lara it would have helped if you would have included the entire error-message `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Nullable<MyValue>'.(2322)`. The way you cropped it, the error-message is misleading, which is worse than no error message at all or "Something went wrong."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = "A"
```

here `"A"` is interpreted as `string`, which is not assignable to your string-literal types.

just do

```
a = "A" as const;
```

(as i'm not sure if `as const` is available in ts 3.7)
you can also try

```
a = "A" as "A";
a = "A" as MyValue;
```